# Why does setInterval works differently in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

What is the difference between the two implementations below? I used the first one that worked perfectly in Chrome then I checked it in Firefox and it said *reference error, it didn't know where is `myFunction`.

```
ReferenceError: changePosition is not defined 
slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
```

Doesn't work in Firefox, works in Chrome

```
setInterval(myFunction,2000);

function myFunction(){ ... }
```

Works in Firefox and Chrome, too

```
function myFunction(){ ... }

setInterval(myFunction,2000);
```

**Details from the code**

```
        function changePosition() {
            if(nextFrame === true){
                if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides - 1) {
                    currentPosition = 0;
                } else {
                    currentPosition++;
                }
                moveSlide();
            }
        }

        function moveSlide() {
            nextFrame = false;

            $('#slideshow_'+id+' .slidesHolder').velocity({
                marginLeft : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
            },{
                complete: function() { 
                    nextFrame = true;
                }
            })
        }

        slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
```

Comment: That is invalid syntax (both). Please post exactly what you have in your test code.

Comment: You're missing the `function` keyword, in the examples (not in your  code), which makes them ungrammatical.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the observation, I'd just mistype my example.

Comment: _I checked it in Firefox and it said reference error_. What exactly error you're getting?

Comment: ReferenceError: changePosition is not defined | slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

Comment: I got it if the setInterval is before the function changePosition and it works perfectly if I use setInterval after the function.